How to sign a kernel module Ubuntu 24.04 LTS
I am new to using Ubuntu. I am trying to install PEAK CAN driver so I can see the CAN messages in LINUX environment using VirtualBox. But it seems as if I need to sign a pcan kernal module... and I really am not sure how to do it. This is the error message I get after running
@jerinj89-VirtualBox:~$ sudo modprobe pcan
@jerinj89-VirtualBox:~$ dmesg | grep pcan
[  149.692697] pcan: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
[  149.692709] pcan: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing -   tainting kernel
[  149.697596] pcan: Release_20240521_n (le)
[  149.697599] pcan: driver config [mod] [isa] [pci] [pec] [usb] 
[  149.697793] usbcore: registered new interface driver pcan
[  149.697797] pcan: major 240.

I need to resolve the below error
pcan: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
I have tried googling this, and followed the steps from https://ubuntu.com/blog/how-to-sign-things-for-secure-boot/
but again got an error EFI variables are not supported on this system for command sudo mokutil --import MOK.der
I cannot find a clear and concise answer with sequential steps. Again, I am fairly new to linux, so any help is welcome. Thanks in advance.

If the kernel is built not by you and requires signature, the only way is to ask someone who is in possession of private keys. Otherwise you need to build your own kernel.

"Secure boot" has nothing common with the Linux kernel modules signing. See e.g. documentation about what module signing actually means and how it is performed. Note that for sign a module for load it into already compiled kernel you need to know the private key.

Since the pcan module appears to have been loaded anyway, your system is not configured to prevent loading of modules with invalid signatures.
